# C# XML serialization complex object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

please I need help for I need to know models I will create for serialize into xml
 I have the serialize method and it doing well 
My question here I need to know best way to create complex  model to do xml file,
here is my xml example file 
  **

```
  <MsgId></MsgId>
  <CreDtTm></CreDtTm>
  <NbOfTxs></NbOfTxs>
  <CtrlSum></CtrlSum>
  <InitgPty>
    <Nm></Nm>
  </InitgPty>
</GrpHdr>
  <PmtInf>
  <PmtInfId></PmtInfId>
  <PmtMtd></PmtMtd>
  <ReqdExctnDt></ReqdExctnDt>
</PmtInf>
  <Dbtr>
    <Nm></Nm>
  </Dbtr>
  <DbtrAcct>
    <Id>
      <Othr>
        <Id></Id>

      </Othr>

    </Id>
  </DbtrAcct>
  <DbtrAgt>
    <FinInstnId></FinInstnId>
    <Nm></Nm>
  </DbtrAgt>
```

**

Comment: The xsd.exe tool can be used to generate c# classes from an XML Schema or sample XML document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe

Comment: The XML in the sample code is not well formed (it can have only one top level element).  I do not believe it will be useful in this form regardless of the tooling.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize xml that has an array at the root level.  You also cannot serialize an xml that is missing opening or closeing tags.  You are missing the opening tag GrpHdr.

Below I fixed these two issue.

```
<root>
  <GrpHdr>
    <MsgId></MsgId>
    <CreDtTm></CreDtTm>
    <NbOfTxs></NbOfTxs>
    <CtrlSum></CtrlSum>
    <InitgPty>
      <Nm></Nm>
    </InitgPty>
  </GrpHdr>
  <PmtInf>
    <PmtInfId></PmtInfId>
    <PmtMtd></PmtMtd>
    <ReqdExctnDt></ReqdExctnDt>
  </PmtInf>
  <Dbtr>
    <Nm></Nm>
  </Dbtr>
  <DbtrAcct>
    <Id>
      <Othr>
        <Id></Id>

      </Othr>

    </Id>
  </DbtrAcct>
  <DbtrAgt>
    <FinInstnId></FinInstnId>
    <Nm></Nm>
  </DbtrAgt>
</root>
```

Comment: so how can I serialize this complex nodes /tags ?please I need any help

Comment: my problem is here in this specific part    <DbtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <Othr>
            <Id>1</Id>
          </Othr>
          
        </Id>
      </DbtrAcct>

Comment: You need thee classes : 1) DbtrAcct 2) Id 3) Othr.  Then inside Othr class you have a property Id.

Comment: by that I may have so many classes !! so is there a simple  way than that?

Comment: The only way using serialization is a class of each tag except to leaf node.  Multiple class can call the same child which can eliminate the number of classes.  Also have a Base Class and Inherited children can save the number of classes.  If you use other libraries like Xml Linq which do not require classes it may simplify the parsing.